# VS Code adding methods without brackets

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code, autocomplete

I am using VS Code for a project written in Flutter.

Whenever I choose a method from the drop-down field in code completion, the method is added without any brackets.

Like when I click on `Table (...)` only `Table` is added., without the brackets.

In the past, adding with the brackets worked, so I believed I must have messed something up in the auto-complete settings, but I can't find any option.

I tried adding `"editor.autoClosingBrackets": "always"` to the settings.json, but that didn't solve the issue.

Anybody has a clue about how to make this work?

[image]

[image]

Comment: I always get this too, wonder how to fix it

Comment: What language are you using? Flutter as well?